# Exec statement with condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use the `exec` command to retrieve info from a stored procedure with a `where` clause. For example.

```
exec f.dbo.c_table 'k'
where ic_no'3'
```

How to use the where condition exactly?

Comment: 1) Use the `where` clause *inside* the SP. 2) Put the results of the SP into a temp table and then select from it with your `where` clause.

Comment: EXEC is not a SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE... you cannot use a WHERE clause ! Add a parameter to your procedure to filter inside the Transact SQL code of the procedure, into the SQL statement (SELECT I suppose).